# Survival (PH) R^2 *decreases* with additional variables

Tags: survival, stata

I am running a R.P. flexible parametric survival model (hazards) in Stata, using the stpm2 package and I have encountered a possibly unusual scenario. My Royston & Sauerbrei’s R^2 (not adjusted) value reduces a lot when additional predictors are added to the model - from 21% to 15% with the inclusion of a 2nd predictor. Importantly, other measures of model fit – AIC and BIC – improve when additional variables are included, and likelihood-ratio tests strongly support the inclusion of additional variables. I’ve not encountered this before and I’m wondering / concerned whether this is diagnostic of some other issue / a red flag.

My understanding is that R^2 should not strictly be interpreted as ‘amount of variance explained’ in this context, but even still, the changes seem suspicious. Is there a clear explanation for this / a broader intuition as to what might be occurring? Nothing in the helpfile or [here](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0600600105) pointed me to an explanation.

The model includes time-varying effects. However, the peculiarity exists when these are removed.

Edit: Example output - both predictors are significant in the model and individually.

[image: Model 1 - single predictor]

[image: Model 2 - 2 predictors]

Comment: Is it possible that your sample size is decreasing as you add variables?

Comment: No, these are nested models